# Dynamically update matplotlib figure in Jupyter notebook with Qt backend

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib

I would like to dynamically update a [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) Figure using the [PyQt](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/) backend in Jupyter notebooks. However, the window freezes, and only after execution of the complete cell the window is shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the behavior of Qt, this is pretty easy to accomplish.
You use `QApplication.processEvents()` to activate the event loop handler, such that the window is shown and processed. You call this at every iteration, et voila!

Example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import sleep
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

%matplotlib qt

# Create a Figure with 10 bars of height 0
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
vals = np.zeros(10)
bars = plt.bar(np.arange(len(vals)), vals)
plt.show()

# Iterate 20x
for i in range(20):
    # Generate some data    
    idx = np.random.randint(0,10)
    vals[idx] += 1

    # Adjust bars and y-lim
    bars[idx].set_height(vals[idx])
    plt.ylim([0, max(vals)+1])

    # Draw scene and update Qt!
    fig.canvas.draw()
    QApplication.processEvents()

    # Some artificial delay
    sleep(0.5)
```